# What would cause an AnyCPU web application to only work in 32 bit mode?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, iis

I have a .net mvc web application hosted on an IIS 7.5 web server. There are several dozen other applications on this web server, all in their own application pools.  ALL application pools are 64bit and things have been working fine for some time.

Last night after making a few client side changes to the site in question I published and received the error, "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.DLL or one of it's dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application.  See screen below.

[image]

I ran into this error several years ago and found that by switching my app pool in IIS to 'enable 32bit applications' fixed it.  This time around however, I want to understand why this is happening.  There should be no reason I can't run in 64bit mode.

I know the cause could be many things so I will just list some of things I have tried.  Perhaps someone has an idea where to start.

- In visual studio 2013 update 4 my application is set to build for 'AnyCPU'.  I have tried building exclusively for 64bit and got the same error.
- I am using EF 6.1.1 with data migrations
- My web server is running windows server 2008 64bit w/ iis 7.5
- My development machine runs windows 7 64bit and IIS 8 express.  My app works fine in this environment
- I do have references to other projects that reference EF.  If their version is not consistent could this be a problem?
- My application targets .net 4.5 and I have that version installed on my server.
- The only changes I made to this commit from the last working one were some client side code and one new migration that involved adding a new nullable string/nvarchar property to a table.
- I did update to visual studio 2013 update 4 between last commit and this one.

Any ideas?  Thanks ahead.

Comment: In your project(s) have you references to 32bit compiled assemblies?